# localstorage item not cleared upon React component unmount

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have some React components and they use localstorage to store some information.
These are tied to state variables with a custom hook:

```
export const useLocalStorage = (key, defaultValue) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
        return getStorageValue(key, defaultValue);
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }, [key, value]);

    return [value, setValue];
}
```

The component uses this like:

```
const [thing, setThing] = useLocalStorage('thing', '');
```

Now, what I want, is to clear this when the component unmounts.

I have tried to clear this with useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        setThing(prevThing => '');
    }
},[]);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I can even console log in the cleanup
function and see that, but the state change and subsequent clearing of the
localstorage doesn't happen. I'm unsure how to get this to properly clear.

Edit (adding getStorageValue):

```
const getStorageValue = (key, defaultValue) => {
    let value;
    try {
        const saved = localStorage.getItem(key);
        value = JSON.parse(saved);

    } catch(err) {
        value = false;
    }

    return value || defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: By properly clearing, do you mean removing the item from localStorage or setting it to an empty string? You can use `localStorage.removeItem(itemName)` to remove the item from local storage.

Comment: Either should be fine. I was avoiding editing localstorage directly to prevent it becoming out of sync with what's in state, but I suppose if the component is unmounting that's irrelevant. A quick test shows that a direct removal does happen. I'd still like to know why it doesn't work as-is though.

Comment: Can you include the code for `getStorageValue`?

Comment: Added as requested.

Comment: You aren’t using the `prevState` value in clearing the state, so why don’t you just call `setThing(“”)` in the cleanup function? I don’t see why this would be an issue, but worth checking since the setState invocation is a bit unorthodox here

Comment: That seems unlikely. It's generally recommended to pass state as a function to ensure you're dealing with the latest values. Even though, I'm not using it, I do this out of habit, and have never had a problem. This also works fine with other localstorage things that are being changed. It seems to be related to the unmounting process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you tried to set the value to `""` expecting the useEffect callback to run in response and set the `localStorage` item to `""`. However, setting the value is a no-op because the component is already unmounting. You should see a warning in the console when this happens.

Luckily you can still access `localStorage` from a cleanup callback as that doesn't depend on the component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, '');
    }
}, [key]);
```

This hook invocation will set the item to `""` when `key` changes or the component is unmounted.

---

As an aside, `Storage.setItem(key, '')` does not unset the key but rather sets an empty string as its value. To unset a key, use `Storage.removeItem(key)`.

Comment: Yeah. I was being sort of generic about unset vs clearing the value. The noop was the only thing I could think of that might be causing this to not happen. I know why they do it, but in this case, the noop state change has consequences which are not, because of the useeffect. Oh well, I'll just have to operate directly with the localstorage for that. Thanks for confirming the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

React component's local state won't know anything about the `localStorage`. If your hook is setting something to local storage, then it's the job of the hook to clear it on unmount if needed.

It won't happen automatically.

Comment: Well, I wasn't removing the localstorage item. I was just setting it to a new value ''. That state change call in unmount, is a hook to the state in useLocalstorage. The useeffect in uselocalstorage updates local storage on the state change.